# javascript to enlarge img

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I've got some problems while trying to change the size of an image when 'mouseover' occurs.

I know it can be done by css, but I need to realize it by js.

JS Codes:

```
// id is passed to this function.
...
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var li;
// generate lists of img from db.
li = document.createElement("li");      
li.innerHTML = '<img src="' + id + '" />';
content.appendChild(li);
addDomListener(li, 'mouseover', function(){
    li.style.height = '600px';
    li.style.width = '800px';
});
```

HTML codes:

```
<div>
  <ul id="content">
  </ul>
</div>
```

seems right, but it doesn't work. I suspect the problem is 'li.style.height'. Could anyone tell me the correct way to realize it? Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were changing the height and width of `li` element itself, instead of the `img` element, for that replace your following code:

```
li.style.height = '600px';
li.style.width = '800px';
```

for this one:

```
li.firstChild.style.height = '600px';
li.firstChild.style.width = '800px';
```

Comment: Thx for ur advice, I'm now implementing ur method, hold a sec plz.

Comment: @Nelson
Thx again, it works! Further discuss, if I add an <a> element to li, like this: <li><a href="linkhere"><img src="url" /></a></li>, will it be secondChild?

Comment: @RenatoGama JS bin is a nice gadget! new here, don't know there is one... To the problem u post, maybe the codes there is not finished as a function..

Comment: @Matt: No, it would be `li.firstChild.firstChild`. Also note that this does not work if you insert whitespaces (text nodes) or other stuff, therefore the use of a selector expression or a direct pointer to the `img` object (like in my answer) should be preferred.

Comment: @Bergi Right, it should be firstChild.firstChild. Thx for reminding me! This method seem to be easier(for me now), I'll work on ur answer and take it seriously.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the dimensions of the li element, not the image itself, so the behaviour is expected. You need to get a pointer to your image first.

In addition, you should use jQuery for manipulating the DOM and modifying an element's style on a mouse event. It will make your like much easier.

Comment: Thx for reply. I get u. Could u say a little more specific about how I point to the img itself? I'm not very familiar with jQuery yet. Can we just use js to realize it for now?

Comment: jQuery selects element with CSS selectors. There is a bit to learn but it's a really powerful method. In you case the simplest is to give an id (for example "test") to your image and select it through `$('#test')`. The whole selectors API is here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Change the size of the `<img>`, not of the `<li>`:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = id;
li.appendChild(img);
content.appendChild(li);
addDomListener(li, 'mouseover', function(){
    img.height = '600px';
    img.width = '800px';
});
```

Comment: I've used the `height` and `width` attributes, which may be suppressed by some CSS styles. You might try `img.style.…`